# I need to create a loop to add up all the values in the rows and columns( more details below)

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

```
#pragma once

namespace My2DArray {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtTable;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btn2D;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  rowSum1;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  rowSum2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  colSum1;



    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  colSum4;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  colSum5;




    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label8;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  colSum2;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  colSum3;



    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label9;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  rowSum3;




    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->txtTable = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->btn2D = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->rowSum1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->rowSum2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->colSum1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->colSum4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->colSum5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->colSum2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->colSum3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->rowSum3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(163, 34);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(51, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"Column 1";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(279, 34);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(51, 13);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label2->Text = L"Column 2";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(409, 34);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(51, 13);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label3->Text = L"Column 3";
            // 
            // txtTable
            // 
            this->txtTable->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 29.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->txtTable->Location = System::Drawing::Point(91, 50);
            this->txtTable->Multiline = true;
            this->txtTable->Name = L"txtTable";
            this->txtTable->Size = System::Drawing::Size(644, 170);
            this->txtTable->TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(26, 61);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(38, 13);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label4->Text = L"Row 1";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this->label5->AutoSize = true;
            this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(26, 106);
            this->label5->Name = L"label5";
            this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(38, 13);
            this->label5->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label5->Text = L"Row 2";
            // 
            // btn2D
            // 
            this->btn2D->Location = System::Drawing::Point(343, 355);
            this->btn2D->Name = L"btn2D";
            this->btn2D->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 34);
            this->btn2D->TabIndex = 6;
            this->btn2D->Text = L"Make Table";
            this->btn2D->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btn2D->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btn2D_Click);
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this->label6->AutoSize = true;
            this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(747, 34);
            this->label6->Name = L"label6";
            this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(58, 13);
            this->label6->TabIndex = 7;
            this->label6->Text = L"Row Sums";
            // 
            // rowSum1
            // 
            this->rowSum1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->rowSum1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(750, 50);
            this->rowSum1->Multiline = true;
            this->rowSum1->Name = L"rowSum1";
            this->rowSum1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 47);
            this->rowSum1->TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // rowSum2
            // 
            this->rowSum2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->rowSum2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(750, 111);
            this->rowSum2->Multiline = true;
            this->rowSum2->Name = L"rowSum2";
            this->rowSum2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 47);
            this->rowSum2->TabIndex = 9;
            // 
            // colSum1
            // 
            this->colSum1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->colSum1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(150, 238);
            this->colSum1->Multiline = true;
            this->colSum1->Name = L"colSum1";
            this->colSum1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 47);
            this->colSum1->TabIndex = 10;
            // 
            // colSum4
            // 
            this->colSum4->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->colSum4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(534, 238);
            this->colSum4->Multiline = true;
            this->colSum4->Name = L"colSum4";
            this->colSum4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 47);
            this->colSum4->TabIndex = 11;
            // 
            // colSum5
            // 
            this->colSum5->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->colSum5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(671, 238);
            this->colSum5->Multiline = true;
            this->colSum5->Name = L"colSum5";
            this->colSum5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 47);
            this->colSum5->TabIndex = 12;
            // 
            // label7
            // 
            this->label7->AutoSize = true;
            this->label7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(547, 34);
            this->label7->Name = L"label7";
            this->label7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(51, 13);
            this->label7->TabIndex = 13;
            this->label7->Text = L"Column 4";
            // 
            // label8
            // 
            this->label8->AutoSize = true;
            this->label8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(668, 34);
            this->label8->Name = L"label8";
            this->label8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(51, 13);
            this->label8->TabIndex = 14;
            this->label8->Text = L"Column 5";
            // 
            // colSum2
            // 
            this->colSum2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->colSum2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(282, 238);
            this->colSum2->Multiline = true;
            this->colSum2->Name = L"colSum2";
            this->colSum2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 47);
            this->colSum2->TabIndex = 15;
            // 
            // colSum3
            // 
            this->colSum3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->colSum3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(396, 238);
            this->colSum3->Multiline = true;
            this->colSum3->Name = L"colSum3";
            this->colSum3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 47);
            this->colSum3->TabIndex = 16;
            // 
            // label9
            // 
            this->label9->AutoSize = true;
            this->label9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(26, 145);
            this->label9->Name = L"label9";
            this->label9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(38, 13);
            this->label9->TabIndex = 17;
            this->label9->Text = L"Row 3";
            // 
            // rowSum3
            // 
            this->rowSum3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->rowSum3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(750, 173);
            this->rowSum3->Multiline = true;
            this->rowSum3->Name = L"rowSum3";
            this->rowSum3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 47);
            this->rowSum3->TabIndex = 18;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(817, 423);
            this->Controls->Add(this->rowSum3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label9);
            this->Controls->Add(this->colSum3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->colSum2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label8);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
            this->Controls->Add(this->colSum5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->colSum4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->colSum1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->rowSum2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->rowSum1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label6);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btn2D);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtTable);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"2D Array Program";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
        Random^ randomNumGen;

    private: System::Void btn2D_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 // Declare Variables
                 const int numRows = 3;
                 const int numCols = 5;
                 int row, col; 
                 int total;
                 int arr2d[numRows][numCols] = {{5, 0, 8, 2, 1}, {6, 7, 6, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
                 int rowSum[] = {0 , 0};
                 String^ strOut = "";

                 // Display results
                 for (row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
                 {
                     for (col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
                         strOut += "         " + (arr2d[row][col]);
                     strOut += "\r\n";
                 }
problem below here ---------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to make a loop (which ever kind doesn't matter to me) to loop through each column and sum up the total in each column and then in each row my problem is I have no idea what kind of loop and what variables to use please help!
                     total = arr2d[0][0] + arr2d[1][0] + arr2d[2][0];
                     colSum1->Text = total.ToString();

```
                 total = arr2d[0][1] + arr2d[1][1] + arr2d[2][1];
                 colSum2->Text = total.ToString();

                  total = arr2d[0][2] + arr2d[1][2] + arr2d[2][2];
                 colSum3->Text = total.ToString();

                 total = arr2d[0][3] + arr2d[1][3] + arr2d[2][3];
                 colSum4->Text = total.ToString();

                 total = arr2d[0][4] + arr2d[1][4] + arr2d[2][4];
                 colSum5->Text = total.ToString();

                 total = arr2d[0][0] + arr2d[0][1] + arr2d[0][2] + arr2d[0][3] + arr2d[0][4];
                 rowSum1->Text = total.ToString();

                 total = arr2d[1][0] + arr2d[1][1] + arr2d[1][2] + arr2d[1][3] + arr2d[1][4];
                 rowSum2->Text = total.ToString();

                 total = arr2d[2][0] + arr2d[2][1] + arr2d[2][2] + arr2d[2][3] + arr2d[2][4];
                 rowSum3->Text = total.ToString();

                 txtTable->Text = strOut;
             }

};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First learn for loops:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm

Then, you're going to need to know the height and width of your grid.  From there, you're going to have to nest the for loops similar to this:

```
textOutput;

//first for loop iterates through each row
for(int row = 0; row< height; row++)
{
    currentRowTotal = 0;

    //nested for loop iterates through each col
    for(int col = 0; col < width; col++)
    {
        //do stuff with the current rowTotal
    }
    //current row totaled, change text output
}

//then do it again for each column (inverse of above)
for(int col = 0; col< width; col++)
{
    currentColTotal = 0;
    for(int row = 0; col < height; row++)
    {
        //do stuff with the current colTotal
    }
    //current col totaled, change text output
}
```

On a note of interest, in C++ the first function is faster than then second because of data locality.  Which means, generally, iterate through the last part of a 2d|3d|4d|ect. array in the innermost for loop if you want it to be quickest.